# JavaFX button sizing - HBox and VBox don't align properly and gaps visible

Tags: button, javafx, layout-manager, vbox, hbox

I'm trying to learn JavaFX, I'm building a calculator, and I'm experiencing some button sizing behaviour which I need guidance on.

Firstly, why does the HBox containing the zero and point buttons seem to have a few pixels free on the right hand side? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8imGf.jpg

And secondly, how can I make the equals button take up more or less horizontal space within the HBox that it sits? I've tried setting its preferred width method but this makes no difference. I guess my problem relates to how nodes are sized when there is limited space.

The full class is below. What I have done is create an HBox for each row of numeric buttons and also the point button. These three rows are then placed inside a VBox, which is placed in an HBox next to the equals button.

I'm reading JavaFX for Dummies, and have looked at many posts etc., but can't work it out!

```
package calculator;

import javafx.application.*;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class UserInterface extends Application {

    static int buttonHeight = 30;
    VBox pane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

//4, 5, 6 numeric buttons 
        //Six button
        Button b6 = new Button("6");
        b6.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        b6.setPrefHeight(b6.getPrefHeight() + buttonHeight);
        HBox.setHgrow(b6, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Five button
        Button b5 = new Button("5");
        b5.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        b5.setPrefHeight(b5.getPrefHeight() + buttonHeight);
        HBox.setHgrow(b5, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Four button
        Button b4 = new Button("4");
        b4.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        b4.setPrefHeight(b4.getPrefHeight() + buttonHeight);
        HBox.setHgrow(b4, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Place the buttons in the 456 HBox
        HBox row456 = new HBox();
        row456.getChildren().addAll(b4, b5, b6);

//1, 2, 3 numeric buttons
        //Button three
        Button b3 = new Button("3");
        b3.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        b3.setPrefHeight(b3.getPrefHeight() + buttonHeight);
        HBox.setHgrow(b3, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Button two
        Button b2 = new Button("2");
        b2.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        b2.setPrefHeight(b2.getPrefHeight() + buttonHeight);
        HBox.setHgrow(b2, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Button one
        Button b1 = new Button("1");
        b1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        b1.setPrefHeight(b1.getPrefHeight() + buttonHeight);
        HBox.setHgrow(b1, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Place the buttons in the 123 HBox
        HBox row123 = new HBox();
        row123.getChildren().addAll(b1, b2, b3);

//Zero and point buttons
        //zero button
        Button zero = new Button("0");
        zero.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        zero.setPrefHeight(zero.getPrefHeight() + buttonHeight);
        HBox.setHgrow(zero, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //point button
        Button point = new Button(".");
        point.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        point.setPrefHeight(point.getPrefHeight() + buttonHeight);
        HBox.setHgrow(point, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Place the buttons in the zeroPoint HBox
        HBox zeroPoint = new HBox();
        zeroPoint.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(zeroPoint, Priority.ALWAYS);
        zeroPoint.getChildren().addAll(zero, point);


//Numeric button rows in a VBox
        VBox intLower = new VBox(row456, row123, zeroPoint);
        HBox.setHgrow(intLower, Priority.ALWAYS);


//Equals button
        Button equals = new Button("=");
        HBox.setHgrow(equals, Priority.ALWAYS);
        equals.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        equals.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

// Numeric button VBox and  equals button inside HBox
        HBox lower = new HBox(intLower, equals);
        lower.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);


//Populate the root pane
        pane = new VBox();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(lower);
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);

//Add the root pane to a scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 210, 285);
        // Finish and show the stage
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Calculator");
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Edit:
I've now tried using a GridPane to assemble this GUI, and am having the same problem with rows not aligning properly and small spaces visible between nodes - it looks like when you take the cheapest quote to renovate a kitchen and later find that none of the cupboards close flush: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r47K1.jpg

```
package calculator;

import javafx.application.*;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class UserInterface extends Application {

    private static int butHeightModifier = 30;
    private static int appWidth = 225 * 2;
    private static int appHeight = 310 * 2;
    private static int numRows = 7;
    private static int numCols = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
//7, 8, 9 numeric buttons 
        //Nine button
        Button b9 = new Button("9");
        b9.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(b9, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(b9, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Eight button
        Button b8 = new Button("8");
        b8.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(b8, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(b8, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Seven button
        Button b7 = new Button("7");
        b7.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(b7, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(b7, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Place the buttons in the 456 HBox
        HBox row789 = new HBox();
        row789.getChildren().addAll(b7, b8, b9);

//4, 5, 6 numeric buttons 
        //Six button
        Button b6 = new Button("6");
        b6.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(b6, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(b6, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Five button
        Button b5 = new Button("5");
        b5.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(b5, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(b5, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Four button
        Button b4 = new Button("4");
        b4.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(b4, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(b4, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Place the buttons in the 456 HBox
        HBox row456 = new HBox();
        row456.getChildren().addAll(b4, b5, b6);

//1, 2, 3 numeric buttons
        //Button three
        Button b3 = new Button("3");
        b3.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(b3, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(b3, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Button two
        Button b2 = new Button("2");
        b2.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(b2, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(b2, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Button one
        Button b1 = new Button("1");
        b1.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(b1, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(b1, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Place the buttons in the 123 HBox
        HBox row123 = new HBox();
        row123.getChildren().addAll(b1, b2, b3);

//Zero and point buttons
        //zero button
        Button zero = new Button("0");
        zero.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(zero, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(zero, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //point button
        Button point = new Button(".");
        point.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(point, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(point, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Place the buttons in the zeroPoint HBox
        HBox zeroPoint = new HBox();
        zeroPoint.getChildren().addAll(zero, point);

//Multiply and division buttons
        Button multiply = new Button("X");
        multiply.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(multiply, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(multiply, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Button division = new Button("/");
        division.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(division, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(division, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Place the buttons in the zeroPoint HBox
        HBox multiDiv = new HBox();
        multiDiv.getChildren().addAll(multiply, division);

//Plus and minus buttons
        Button plus = new Button("+");
        plus.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(plus, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(plus, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Button minus = new Button("-");
        minus.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(minus, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(minus, Priority.ALWAYS);

        //Place the buttons in the zeroPoint HBox
        HBox plusMinus = new HBox();
        plusMinus.getChildren().addAll(plus, minus);

//Equals button
        Button equals = new Button("=");
        equals.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

// Create GridPane
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

// Set row and column constraints
        ColumnConstraints col = new ColumnConstraints();
        col.setPercentWidth(20);
        grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col, col, col, col, col);

        RowConstraints row = new RowConstraints();
        row.setPercentHeight(14.2857);
        grid.getRowConstraints().addAll(row, row, row, row, row, row, row);

//Set filling constraint
        for (int r = 0; r <= numRows; r++) {
            RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
            rc.setFillHeight(true);
            rc.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            grid.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
        }
        for (int c = 0; c <= numCols; c++) {
            ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
            cc.setFillWidth(true);
            cc.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            grid.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
        }

//Add nodes to grid pane
        grid.add(zeroPoint, 0, 6, 3, 1);
        grid.add(equals, 3, 5, 2, 2);
        grid.add(row123, 0, 5, 3, 1);
        grid.add(row456, 0, 4, 3, 1);
        grid.add(row789, 0, 3, 3, 1);
        grid.add(multiDiv, 3, 4, 2, 1);
        grid.add(plusMinus, 3, 3, 2, 1);

// Create the scene and the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Calculator");
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(appWidth);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(appHeight);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably better to use a `GridPane` for the `Buttons`.

Comment: I'll definitely give GridPane a shot - I have yet to read that chapter. But I'd still like to know why the HBox/VBox combinations act like this.

Comment: I created a `GridPane` layout but I am going to hold back on posting it unless you run into new problems.

Comment: Also, I personally would use `SceneBuilder` for a static layout.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. I'll experiment and come back with any questions.

Comment: Ok, I tried GridPane and get the same problem. Any ideas? I've edited my post with the new code.

Comment: When I said to use `GridPane`, I meant you should get rid of your row `HBoxes` and used `GridPane` instead

Answer (score 1):

The `GridLines` are showing so that you can see what's going on with `Buttons` like the equal and decimal buttons.

**The Equal Button extends more than one row and the Decimal Button extends more than one column**

```
buttonLayout.add(buttonList.get(11), 3, 0, 1, 4);//Equal Button
buttonLayout.add(buttonList.get(10), 1, 3, 2, 1);//Decimal Button
```

> add(Node child, int columnIndex, int rowIndex, int colspan, int rowspan)
>   Adds a child to the gridpane at the specified column,row position and spans.

**This code allows the `Buttons` to fill the `Cells`.** code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344702/how-do-i-get-buttons-to-fill-a-javafx-gridpane).

```
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 4; rowIndex++) {
        RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
        rc.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS) ; // allow row to grow
        rc.setFillHeight(true); // ask nodes to fill height for row
        // other settings as needed...
        buttonLayout.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
    }
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < 4; colIndex++) {
        ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
        cc.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS) ; // allow column to grow
        cc.setFillWidth(true); // ask nodes to fill space for column
        // other settings as needed...
        buttonLayout.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
    }
```

> Full Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.*;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class UserInterface extends Application {

    VBox root = new VBox();
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    TextField display = new TextField("");
    List<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList();
    GridPane buttonLayout = new GridPane();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Button tempButton = new Button(Integer.toString(i));            
            buttonList.add(tempButton);
        }        
        buttonList.add(new Button("."));
        buttonList.add(new Button("="));    


        for(int i = 0; i < buttonList.size(); i++)
        {
            buttonList.get(i).setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        buttonLayout.add(buttonList.get(7), 0, 0);
        buttonLayout.add(buttonList.get(8), 1, 0);
        buttonLayout.add(buttonList.get(9), 2, 0);
        buttonLayout.add(buttonList.get(11), 3, 0, 1, 4);


        buttonLayout.add(buttonList.get(4), 0, 1);
        buttonLayout.add(buttonList.get(5), 1, 1);
        buttonLayout.add(buttonList.get(6), 2, 1);

        buttonLayout.add(buttonList.get(1), 0, 2);
        buttonLayout.add(buttonList.get(2), 1, 2);
        buttonLayout.add(buttonList.get(3), 2, 2);

        buttonLayout.add(buttonList.get(0), 0, 3);
        buttonLayout.add(buttonList.get(10), 1, 3, 2, 1);


        buttonLayout.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        buttonLayout.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 4; rowIndex++) {
            RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
            rc.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS) ; // allow row to grow
            rc.setFillHeight(true); // ask nodes to fill height for row
            // other settings as needed...
            buttonLayout.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
        }
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < 4; colIndex++) {
            ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
            cc.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS) ; // allow column to grow
            cc.setFillWidth(true); // ask nodes to fill space for column
            // other settings as needed...
            buttonLayout.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
        }

        VBox.setVgrow(buttonLayout, Priority.ALWAYS);
        root.getChildren().addAll(display, buttonLayout);


        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. When I use a GridPane by itself the buttons do align properly. However, what if I need to have two buttons span three cells? Doesn't this require an HBox? I really want to know why HBox fails to align. Button, HBox, and GridPane are all nodes - when it comes to alignment, shouldn't they all be treated the same?

Comment: I specifically point out two situations in my example where the column or row span more than one. The equal button span 4 rows and the decimal button span 2.

Comment: I see that. My question was how to get 2 buttons to span 3 cells. I realise now that this can be achieved by doubling the number of columns and having each button occupy 3 cells, but that still doesn't explain why HBox's fail to align. I'm not trying to disparage your solution, because it works, but I also want to try and understand why HBox and VBox are behaving as they are.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't want to go through your code to figure it out. Based on your original picture, I think your layout should have an `HBox` as the root. You should have added a `VBox` and a `Button`(Equal Button) to the root. In your `VBox`, you should have added your three `HBox` with the `Buttons`. This layout should solve your gap problem.